# Can't post image file into given directory with $_FILES function

Tags: php

I have two pretty much similar cases of adding image files to directory and they both work, but I don't know why this one doesn't, since it's done on the same principles.

And since it's not pasting into the "show" directory, the output is following:

[image]

add-album.php

```
<?php
    include "config.php";
    
    if (isset($_POST["submit_album"])) {
        $album = $_POST["album_name"];
        $album_prikazna = $_POST["album_prikazna"];

        $photo = $_FILES["album_prikazna"]["album_name"];
        $upload = "show/".$photo;
        
        $add_album = $conn->query("INSERT INTO gallery_albums (album_name, album_prikazna) VALUES ('$album', '$album_prikazna')");
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['album_prikazna']['album_name'], $upload);

        header("Location: fotogalerije.php?add_album_action=successfull");
    
    }
?>
```

fotogalerije.php

```
<div class="container">
        <!--Images-->
        <div class="">
            <h3>Arhivi</h3>
                <form method="post" action="add-album.php">
                    <label>Dodaj novi album:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="album_name" /> <input type="submit" name="submit_album" value="Add" /><br>
                    <input type="file" class="mt-3" name="album_prikazna">
                </form><br>
            <?php
                if (isset($_GET["add_album_action"])) {
                    if ($_GET["add_album_action"] == "successfull") { ?>
                    Nov album dodan!<br><br>
                <?php }
                }
            ?>

            <div class="">
                <?php
                    $albums = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM gallery_albums");
                        while ($album_data = $albums->fetch_assoc()) {
                        
                        $photos = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM gallery_photos WHERE album_id = ".$album_data["album_id"]."");
                ?>
                    <div class="p-0 m-0">
                        <img src="<?php echo $album_data['album_prikazna']; ?>"  width="125" class="p-1" />

                        <a href="view-album.php?album_id=<?php echo $album_data["album_id"] ?>">
                        <?php echo $album_data["album_name"];
                        $imagePrikazna = $album_data["album_prikazna"];
                        ?>
                        
                        
                        
                        (<?php echo $photos->num_rows; ?>)</a>
                        <?php }
                    
                        ?>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--!Images-->
```

Comment: Without seeing the server layout I'd hazard a guess `show/`  isn't in the same directory as the `add-album.php` script so you need to use a relative path

Comment: I see two potential issues. 1. `$_POST["album_prikazna"]` should be undefined since `album_prikazna` is a `file`-input. 2. `$_FILES["album_prikazna"]` should be undefined since the form is missing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute/value (which means the file won't be sent with the form on submit)

Comment: akaBase It's in the same directory.
@MagnusEriksson added the enctype, still doesn't work.

Comment: `$_FILES["album_prikazna"]["album_name"]` should be `$_FILES["album_prikazna"]["name"]`. Please refer to [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) about how to handle file uploads. You should also do some  debugging to narrow the issue down. I also pointed out another issue in my previous comment.

Comment: ...and with `move_uploaded_file()`, you should use `$_FILES["album_prikazna"]["tmp_name"]`